# Can i edit android:launchMode="singleTask" with Expo ? (react native)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I searched this issue, but i didn't find the solution.

I need edit android manifest or equivalent in expo, with this:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Is posible edit this in expo? In android project native i edit androidmanifest.xml

But in react native with expo, i don't have manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

today it is no longer necessary to perform "eject". I did this using config-plugins in the Expo SDK 48 version.

1 - Createa a file for plugin, example: `android-manifest-launch-mode-plugin.js`

2 - Add this code.

```js
const { withAndroidManifest } = require('@expo/config-plugins');

module.exports = function withAndroidStrategiesPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, config => {
    config.modResults.manifest.application[0].activity[0].$[
      'android:launchMode'
    ] = 'singleTask'; // SingleTask/SingleMode
    return config;
  });
};
```

3 - In app.json, add the plugin:

```json
...
plugins: [ ['./android-manifest-launch-mode-plugin'] ]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,  you cannot set this property with expo. You'll need to [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) your app if you want to do that level of native customization. Ejection will generate the native projects for you, then you can make native changes like your normally would, but you won't be able to run with expo anymore and you'll have to use the CLI or the native IDEs